# regex fails to find in Python

Tags: python, regex

With a given string:
    Surname,MM,Forename,JTA19 R <first.second@domain.com>

I can match all the groups with this:

```
([A-Za-z]+),([A-Z]+),([A-Za-z]+),([A-Z0-9]+)\s([A-Z])\s<([A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})
```

However, when I apply it to Python it always fails to find it

```
regex=re.compile(r"(?P<lastname>[A-Za-z]+),"
                 r"(?P<initials>[A-Z]+)"
                 r",(?P<firstname>[A-Za-z]+),"
                 r"(?P<ouc1>[A-Z0-9]+)\s"
                 r"(?P<ouc2>[A-Z])\s<"
                 r"(?P<email>[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})"                       
                 )
```

I think I've narrowed it down to this part of email:

```
[A-Z0-9._%+-]
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
r"(?P<email>[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})"
```

with

```
r"(?P<email>[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})"
```

to allow for lowercase letters too.

Comment: doh! sorry, I was testing in notepad++ and it must do regex with case insensitive turned on.

Comment: Add `flags=re.IGNORECASE` to the `compile` method to avoid all those `[A-Za-z]`s

Answer (score 1):

You are passing multiple strings to the compile method, you need to pass in one, whole, regular expression.

```
exp = '''
         (?P<lastname>[A-Za-z]+),
         (?P<initials>[A-Z]+),
         (?P<firstname>[A-Za-Z]+),
         (?P<ouc1>[A-Z0-9]+)\s
         (?P<ouc2>[A-Z])\s<
         (?P<email>[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})'''

regex = re.compile(exp, re.VERBOSE)
```

Although I have to say, your string is just comma separated, so this might be a bit easier:

```
>>> s = "Surname,MM,Forename,JTA19 R <first.second@domain.com>"
>>> lastname,initials,firstname,rest = s.split(',')
>>> ouc1,ouc2,email = rest.split(' ')
>>> lastname,initials,firstname,ouc1,ouc2,email[1:-1]
('Surname', 'MM', 'Forename', 'JTA19', 'R', 'first.second@domain.com')
```

Comment: thanks, I'm helping to run a python course at work (I'm a newbie too) and last week we did regex so thought I'd add it :)